# Color only specific countries based on values in a different data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, data-visualization

I'm a beginner in R and I'm trying to make a world map, which would color specific countries based on their GDP per capita, which is stored in another data frame. Here is my code (found online):

```
install.packages(c("cowplot", "googleway", "ggplot2", "ggrepel", "ggspatial", "libwgeom", "sf", "rnaturalearth", "rnaturalearthdata", "rgeos"))

library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("rgeos")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = world) +
geom_sf() +
xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
ggtitle("World map", subtitle = paste0("(", length(unique(world$name)), " countries)"))
```

This brings a map with 241 countries. However, my data frame with GDPs only stores information on 182 countries. So, when trying to use FILL= I receive an error:

```
ggplot(data = world) +
geom_sf(aes(fill = GDP.data$`US$`)) +
scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt") 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (241): fill
```

How can I overcome this problem and still make R color those countries which I have in my data frame?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not joining your data to the map df?

Comment: @stefan should I then make the dummy variables for the missing 59 country GDPs?

Comment: No. No need to make any dummies. When joining the missing countries will be assigned NAs by default.

Comment: If run in problems with the join I would suggest you add a snippet of your GDP data to your post, e.g. type `dput(head(GDP.data))` into the R console and paste the output starting with `structure(...` into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example, and follows @stefan's advice about joining your data to the map data frame.

In this example, I created a limited data frame containing gdp information `my_gdp` on selected countries:

```
gdp_data <- data.frame(
  name = c("Australia", "China", "Brazil"),
  my_gdp = c(1.43, 13.61, 1.86)
)

       name my_gdp
1 Australia   1.43
2     China  13.61
3    Brazil   1.86
```

You can `merge` (or use `dplyr::left_join`) so that `my_gdp` will be added to your `world` data frame. Using `all.x` will make sure all countries still remain for plotting, and fill in `NA` where there is no gdp values.

```
plot_data <- merge(world, gdp_data, by = "name", all.x = TRUE)
```

Then, you use only this final data frame, `plot_data`, to create your plot. This will be easier to manage than referencing two different data frames in `ggplot`, and ensures you have the same number of rows of data for plotting countries and filling in gdp.

```
ggplot(data = plot_data) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = my_gdp)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt") +
  ggtitle("World map (GDP in trillions $)", subtitle = paste0("(", length(unique(world$name)), " countries)"))
```

**Plot**

[image: gdp plot]